# Stack Overflow Widget

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, widgets

I'd love to have a Stack Overflow widget which randomly shows some of the questions being answered since there is a lot of activity on the site and most of it is interesting for beginners. Is there anything available?

Comment: See http://stackapps.com/

Comment: For a simple widget see https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair

Answer (score 2):

A [reddit widget](http://www.reddit.com/domain/stackoverflow.com/widget/) exists.

Answer (score 2):

There's a SO widget at [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/domain/stackoverflow.com/widget/), but I guess this isn't exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You could use yahoo pipes to do some filtering on the rss feed from https://stackoverflow.com/feeds.

There you could filter by topics of interest, by parsing of the feed.

Then you could publish it and embedded code for your blog, in your google home page, etc.

However if you want it to appear in your desktop, then you should looking into doing something with Yahoo Widgets or Adobe AIR. It could be a nice learning experience.

Comment: Or use geek tools to put the parsed version on the desktop

Answer (score 1):

You could try an RSS widget with some of the RSS feeds for Hot or New questions. I don't know of a specific SA one though.